# Android - reopen outgoing call screen

Tags: android

I have this code to make a phone call:

```
if (intent == null){
     intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);    
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
     intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));    
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```

During the "phone call" the user is able to back to my activity where this code is located. (on a click button)

If user press this button again then another 'phone call' begins in hold state.

I know that I can get the current status phone with TelephonyManager, and with this status I can disable the button if status = CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK,  but what I want, is **reopen** the OUTGOING CALL SCREEN.  Like the click on 'notification bar' when you have an active 'phone call'.

I don't want to hang up, (I know about the restrictions) I just want to reopen the calling screen.

I will appreciate for your help.